How are the base fee and the blob base fee trustlessly relayed from Ethereum to Optimism?
I was reading Optimism's docs on Transaction Fees, and I noticed these statements:

The L1 Data Fee is most heavily influenced by the Ethereum base fee that is continuously and trustlessly relayed from Ethereum to OP Mainnet.
...
The current Ethereum base fee and/or blob base fee (trustlessly relayed from Ethereum).

Little explanation is provided on how the fees are trustlessly relayed from Ethereum. How does that happen?

Relaying GitHub user hash1go answer from a related GitHub discussion:

The information regarding gas prices is obtained from the predeploy address GasPriceOracle. This GasPriceOracle in turn retrieves its information from another predeploy address, L1Block. The L1Block contract is updated through system transactions that are initiated by a system account.
The data from L1 is fetched using an RPC URL to connect to an Ethereum node. Therefore, as I understand it, the system trusts the Ethereum node it references, making it not strictly trustless.

So it looks like the data relay is not trustless, after all.
